# What does `\?` mean in a regular expression?

Tags: c#, regex

May I know what `\?` means in a regular expression? For example, what is its significance in this expression.

I have used this for validating 7 digit telephone no

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: this might be useful: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10004/what-does-mean-in-a-regular-expression

Comment: **[The fifth hit when Googling](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=What+does+%60%5C%3F%60+mean+in+a+regular+expression%3F)** your exact question would have answered your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The properly-escaped "?" will match that exact character, the "?", as it appears in the text.
For instance, if you do

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"\d{3}-\?\d{4}");
```

, you will be able to get a positive match for 123-?1234.
If you want to get a positive match for 1231234 OR 123-1234, you can use the special character "?" without escape, like this:

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"\d{3}-?\d{4}");
```

P.S. for C# .NET, I find the best regex-testing place online is [MyRegexTester](http://www.myregextester.com/index.php). If you use it for C#, don't forget to check the appropriate "C# .NET" checkbox.

P.P.S. as per the comment, putting "\s*" into the regex will match any length white space (spaces and tabs included), "\ ?" will match an optional space, and "[ ]" will match exactly one space (no less).

Comment: i think he want's to match also the blank character, not only the minus sign as separator of the two Group of number therefore your regex should be @"\d{3}[ -]?\d{4} at least

Answer (score 2):

"\?" means "?" itself. "\" - is escape character. "?" is quantifier and "\" is used to escape it.

Answer (score 2):

> I have used this for validating 7 digit telephone no
>
> ```
> "[[:number:]]\{3\}[ -]\?[[:number:]]\{4\}"
> ```

Looking at your example,  it seems that you are talking about **BRE**, then the `\` (escaping) gave `?` special meaning: `one or zero[ -]`

If it is **ERE/PCRE**, the `\`  will take that speical meaning away from `?`, that is, `\?` means literal question mark: `?`

Answer (score 0):

"\?" escapes "?" that have a special meaning in the regex (0 or 1 match) so "\?" escapes it and identifies the literal "?"

your regex looks strange to me, it looks that all the special character are escaped (also "{" ) and doesn't appear to be valid from what i know.
i think you want to write

```
"\d{3}[ -]?\d{4}"
```

if you want to match something that respect the pattern or

```
"^\d{3}[ -]?\d{4}$"
```

if you want to have a match something that is exactly the pattern